# How to dynamically and elegantly change colour of geom_text based on filling value

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I have this heatmap with value labels added to each tile

```
require(ggplot2)
require(RColorBrewer)
require(dplyr)

jBuPuFun <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 9, "BuPu"))
paletteSize <- 256
jBuPuPalette <- jBuPuFun(paletteSize)

nba <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv")
nba$Name <- with(nba, reorder(Name, PTS))
nba.m <- melt(nba)
nba.m <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform,
               rescale = rescale(value))

ggplot(nba.m, aes(variable, Name)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = jBuPuPalette[1],
                       mid = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize/2],
                       high = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize],
                       midpoint = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(fill = rescale, label = round(rescale, 1)), colour = "white")
```

Nevertheless labels maintain a uniform colour (white) which make them difficult to read when the background is also light.

[image]

Is there any elegant way to dynamically define the color of each `geom_text` based on the filling value?

Answer (score 1):

If you color the text in the reverse of the fill, you can get decent results.  I changed the midpoint of the reverse coloring to "steelblue" because the colors will be hard to differentiate at the midpoint if you don't tweak it there.

```
p <- ggplot(nba.m, aes(variable, Name)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), color="white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = jBuPuPalette[1],
                       mid = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize/2],
                       high = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize],
                       midpoint = 0.5) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = jBuPuPalette[paletteSize],
                       mid = "steelblue",
                       high = jBuPuPalette[1],
                       midpoint = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(fill = rescale, color=rescale, label = round(rescale, 1)))
```